# I dont understand my mysql query never returns any rows

Tags: php, html

I don't understand why my querys dont work?

They immediately go to else and skips the if block which tests for the number of rows returned. I keep getting 3 messages that say I have a project that starts with ap / es / wb and I dont know why. I'm realy stuck on this one.

```
$username="root";
$password="23994";
$database="urenselector";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//button bezig joey mikkers
$query= "SELECT projecten.keuze_selectie, projecten.do, projecten.vak, projecten.uren,        projecten.proj_id,".
" urenlijst.username, urenlijst.proj_status FROM projecten,urenlijst Where projecten.proj_id = urenlijst.proj_id AND urenlijst.username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

 //die($query);

$result=mysql_query($query);
//$button_name = "btn".$row['proj_id'];
//if(isset($_GET[$button_name]))
//{

if($result)
{
    $query2= "SELECT urenlijst.proj_status FROM urenlijst WHERE proj_status = 'b' and username = " . $_SESSION['user'];
    $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
    $query3= "SELECT projecten.vak, urenlijst.username, urenlijst.proj_id, urenlijst.proj_status FROM projecten, urenlijst WHERE vak = 'AP' and proj_status = 'b' and username = " . $_SESSION['user'];
        $result3=mysql_query($query3);
        $numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($result3);
        $query4= "SELECT projecten.vak, urenlijst.username, urenlijst.proj_id, urenlijst.proj_status FROM projecten, urenlijst WHERE vak = 'ES' and proj_status = 'b' and username = " . $_SESSION['user'];
        $result4=mysql_query($query4);
        $numrows3 = mysql_num_rows($result4);
        $query5= "SELECT projecten.vak, urenlijst.username, urenlijst.proj_id, urenlijst.proj_status FROM projecten, urenlijst WHERE vak = 'WB' and proj_status = 'b' and username = " . $_SESSION['user'];
        $result5=mysql_query($query5);
        $numrows4 = mysql_num_rows($result5);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $button_name = "btn".$row['proj_id'];
            if(isset($_GET[$button_name]))  
            {

                //print_r($numrows);
                $message = "";
                $message1 = "";
                $message2 = "";
                if($numrows3 < 1)
                    {
                        echo 'test1';
                        if($numrows > 2)
                            {
                                $message = "je hebt al drie projecten geselecteerd met status \"bezig\"";
                            }
                            else
                            {                   
                                mysql_query("UPDATE urenlijst SET proj_status = 'b' WHERE proj_id = ".$row['proj_id']);
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $message2 = "je hebt al een project geselecteerd met het vak ES";
                    }   
                    if($numrows4 < 1)
                    {   
                    echo 'test2';
                            if($numrows > 2)
                            {
                                $message = "je hebt al drie projecten geselecteerd met status \"bezig\"";
                            }
                            else
                            {                   
                                mysql_query("UPDATE urenlijst SET proj_status = 'b' WHERE proj_id = ".$row['proj_id']);
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $message1 = "je hebt al een project geselecteerd met het vak WB";   
                    }   
                if($numrows2 < 1)
                {           
                echo 'test3' . $numrows2;                                                       
                            if($numrows > 2)
                            {
                                $message = "je hebt al drie projecten geselecteerd met status \"bezig\"";
                            }
                            else
                            {                   
                                mysql_query("UPDATE urenlijst SET proj_status = 'b' WHERE proj_id = ".$row['proj_id']);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $message = "je hebt al een project geselecteerd met het vak AP";    
                        }   


                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions. Use PDO or mysqli_* functions instead

Comment: Is this some kind of contest to write the most difficult to follow logic you can think of?  It's bad enough that the variable names are just meaningless numbers, but can those numbers *at least* consistently line up with one another?  As for the question... Which of all these crazy if/else blocks isn't working?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  I strongly suspect that you're having trouble with this code *because* it's such a mess.

Comment: @David We were all beginners once, so let's take it easy. at JoeyMikkers You should clean up your code a bit, read the php docs and not use deprecated functions until you understand where your problem is. Properly formatting code with whitespace so it's formatting corresponds to it's semantic structure also help to debug. Next try to explain your problem to someone who has never seen your code before (it's called [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) and then rewrite your question to explain us as well as you explained the duck ;)

Comment: Btw, if your numresults is always smaller than 1, either is zero or it is negative, so why don't you do `error_log( print_r( $numrowsX, true ) );` and look in your php error log what it actually is? We can't really help you if you don't understand the code you write. Also install phpmyadmin and look in there, it's much easier to test if your queries are correct when you can see the results and the table itself directly.

Answer (score 0):

You used $_SESSION, please check that array prior to use it in query and put

```
 session_start(); // at your first line of script
```